# How to DELETE nodes or relationship with NULL properties in neo4j 2.0 with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created some nodes and relationships within these. But while doing these something wrong happened. I want to delete all nodes having "SGS", except node with ID 2.

Following is script I ran to create node and relationships:

(Please also suggest how to EDIT this one, if possible)

I tried DELETE (along with match, where, IS NULL, etc) with some different trial and error methods but unable to achieve same. Please Help.

Comment: Hi, as this was my first question on SE, you might found it messy. I request you to bare me this time.

Comment: Regarding your query, you have a '<br>' in there at line 15.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like all your nodes have a name, except the node that you want deleted.
So you can try

```
match n
WHERE NOT (HAS (n.name)) //find all nodes with no name property
with n
match n-[r]-() //find all nodes connected to that node
delete r,n //delete its relations and then the node itself
```

(note not tested)

Looks like in your create statement above, you've use (rkn) instead of (rk) and also probably (answ) instead of something else. So (rkn)-[:READ]->(bk1) will just create a node with no properties to represent rkn and a READ relation to OneNight@CallCenter. You just have to verify and fix those.

e.g. the relationships all refer to a node called (rkn) so I renamed the rk node in your create statement to rkn. Please also verify that every node you refer to in your relationships actually maps to a node in your create statement.

> **NOTE**: HAS is no longer supported in Cypher, please use EXISTS instead!

Comment: Thanks Luanne, It worked. I just started to work on this technology 3days ago, so was not aware about "WITH/HAS" etc. Is it possible to answer that how to edit the same(what I have mistaken while creation)?

Comment: I tried with this early (as I am aware about use of UNIQUE) but got (and yet getting) same error:This pattern is not supported for CREATE UNIQUE.

Comment: Your question about the PatternException is a different question than the one about deleting nodes, so you should ask it separately. If you do, someone might answer that `CREATE UNIQUE` requires some part of the pattern to be bound already–first match something, then create unique rels and nodes from that something, i.e. `MATCH (a {name:"A"}) CREATE UNIQUE a-[:R]->(b {name:"B"})`. If you want unique single nodes use `MERGE`.

Answer (score 4):

This one worked for me

```
match (n) WHERE NOT (EXISTS (n.name)) DETACH DELETE n
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above will work currently in cypher.

Try below cypher query. This works:

//find all nodes with no name property.

MATCH (n) WHERE NOT ((n.name)IS NOT NULL)

//detach all its relationships and delete the found node i.e. empty node.

DETACH DELETE n