# How to UPDATE set of created nodes and relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have created about 15 nodes and (their) 29 relationships. But something went wrong, like  while Relating, I used different node id and some kind of orphan nodes and relationships got formed. Now I want to UPDATE that. I gone through deleting those (null) nodes and kept my rest data as it is. You can refer to script here : [How to DELETE nodes or relationship with NULL properties in neo4j 2.0 with cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949508/how-to-delete-nodes-or-relationship-with-null-properties-in-neo4j-2-0-with-cyphe)

As I am new to neo4j, any answers and (more/good) suggestions will be very helpful to me! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest is to recreate the data.

Otherwise you can do a full scan and check for the non-existance of properties

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE not has(n.prop)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer Michael, but thinks that this will help me in some other context/scenario. Because I dont want to go with delete my Graph(data). Will surely vote up ur answer, once reached to 15 reputations.