# Empty Nodes Which Can't Be Deleted

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I noticed recently that there's some nodes in an instance of of my Neo4J whereby some nodes have no properties and are simply empty objects. I retrieve these nodes by doing the following query

```
MATCH (n:Location) where NOT (EXISTS (n.name)) return n
```

This gives me three nodes, each with their own id as seen below.
[image: Nodes with no props]

However, when I select table view I see three empty objects (no id or anything). Screenshot again below.
[image: Empty objects on Neo]

I've tried deleting the nodes which gives a success statement, but they still exist after running a return statement even though Neo4j says they're deleted.
The delete statement used was:

```
MATCH (n:Location) where NOT (EXISTS (n.name)) detach delete n
```

I've tried running return statements on their id (e.g. 3443) but nothing is returned.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to DELETE nodes or relationship with NULL properties in neo4j 2.0 with cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20949508/1243762)

Comment: Do you have a load process somewhere that can recreate those empty nodes ?

Comment: No I don't have a load process unfortunately. This was found on a production server so I'm not sure how long they've been there or anything. I can't seem to get any results with the query provided in the link.

Comment: your queries are OK and what is weird is that your empty nodes have changed their `id`. This can only happened if they are recreated (a node `ID` doesn't change in time)

Comment: What do you mean by "running a return statement"? A bare `return` statement will (usually) show you nothing about the DB. Can you show the full query?

Comment: (1) The table view only shows node properties, it doesn't include labels or internal ID. (2) If you delete and return a node in the same cypher, the return results have the nodes no longer in the DB. (your given example suggests this isn't the case) (3) When fetching by id, did you use `WHERE ID(n)=3443`? (4) What are the <id> values of the nodes before and after the delete? (5) If you run the cypher `:history` (that's the full cypher query). Do you recognize all the recent queries?